# Python Pygame press key to create a rectangle or any graphy

Tags: python, pygame

First I am create a rectangle and put it onto the center of the screen
sencond i want to press a key to show this rectangle
when i exe the `bullet.bullet_move(setting)` and `bullet.draw_bullet(setting)`there's no respond
the code as blew:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import pygame as p
import sys

class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=p.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        p.display.set_caption("Bullet")
        self.bullet_s=1
        self.bullet_w=100
        self.bullet_h=300
        self.bullet_c=(0,0,0)

class Bullet(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_rect=setting.screen.get_rect()
        self.screen_center=self.screen_rect.center

        self.bullet=""
        self.bullet.center=self.screen_center
        self.color=setting.bullet_c
        self.speed=setting.bullet_s
#        self.centery=float(self.bullet.centery)
    def bullet_move(self,setting):
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==p.K_UP:
                    self.bullet=p.Rect((0,0),(setting.bullet_w,setting.bullet_h))
                    self.bullet.center=self.screen_center
#        self.y -= self.speed
#        self.bullet.y=self.y
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        p.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.bullet)


def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    bullet=Bullet(setting)


    while True:
       bullet.bullet_move(setting)
       setting.screen.fill((255,0,0))
       bullet.draw_bullet(setting)
       p.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bullet_move` is the wrong place to do the event handling. Remove it!

```py
class Bullet(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_rect=setting.screen.get_rect()
        self.screen_center=self.screen_rect.center
        self.bullet=p.Rect((0,0),(setting.bullet_w,setting.bullet_h))
        self.bullet.center=self.screen_center
        self.color=setting.bullet_c
        self.speed=setting.bullet_s
        self.centery=float(self.bullet.centery)
    def bullet_move(self,setting):
         self.bullet.y -= self.speed
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        p.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.bullet)
```

Create a list of bullets (`bullets = []`) and spawn a new bullet when <kbd>UP</kbd> is pressed. Create a bullet and `.append` it to `bullets`. Bullets can be moved (`bullet_move`) and drawn (`draw_bullet`) in `for`-loops:

```py
def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)

    bullets = []
    while True:
       for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_UP:
                    bullets.append(Bullet(setting))

       for bullet in bullets:
           bullet.bullet_move(setting)
       setting.screen.fill((255,0,0))
       for bullet in bullets:
           bullet.draw_bullet(setting)
       p.display.flip()
```

Or use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)

    bullets = p.sprite.Group()
    while True:
       for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == p.K_UP:
                    bullets.add(Bullet(setting))

    # [...]
```

Comment: I follow the book 《python crash course》to do the project alian，is this code `bullets=p.sprite.Group` the same as the `bullets=[]` ? and why to use twice `for bullet in bullets`??

Comment: @M_Sea It is similar, it's even better. [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) is a container which can hold [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects. You can use it like a list. Sprites are added by `.add` rather than `.append`. See the last section of the answer, which I've added right now.